# What is a jamfile?

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

I'm trying to use the boost_1_55_0 libraries and I keep coming across references to jamfiles.

What are jamfiles?

Why are there things like bjam and multiple versions of jamfiles?

Comment: See [Boost.Build](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/).

Comment: Pretty common problem in C++, everybody comes up with their own build system.  There's none to rule them all so never any guarantee of success.  Cross-platform promises are weak when you can't even build the damn thing.  So Boost did too, a jamfile says what needs to be built by bjam.  Goes wrong all the time anyway :(

Comment: An even bigger problem than the existence of various make systems is that the compilation model of C/C++ simply sucks and you can put your cpp/header files wherever you want and opensource makefiles sometimes tend to overwrite/modify existing sources. Not to mention that we have header files (in the 21th century!!!) like we had include files in case of assembly and usually the order/location of the include directories is a mess. Sooner or later all build systems become monsters because they try to support the compilation of all opensource monster source trees and this is simply impossible.

Comment: @pasztorpisti "opensource makefiles sometimes tend to overwrite/modify existing sources" - citation needed. There's nothing particular about open-source "monster" source trees.

Comment: @sehe Well, its not actually the makefile that modifies the sources but the scripts executed by make. Generating a config.h should be enough. In my opinion both the build system and the organization of the sources should be more stricter as it is in case of some more modern languages.

Comment: @pasztorpisti I hear you: +1 for modular compilation, +1 for an end to auto-tools. But, for the rest, I don't see how this contributes to "monster source trees" and think you're conflating the troubles of portable C/C++ codebases with bad organization/build tooling. This seems off-topic at best :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Jam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce_Jam) is an open source make system built by Perforce.

Bjam is a boost variant of jam. One of the advantages of jam is that it is explicitly designed to be a platform independent build system, in contrast to other build systems such as make.